# Why do I get Intellisense in vscode when using `require` but not when using `import`

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

In VS Code, when I import jquery using `import $ from 'jquery';`, Intellisense isn't working. This is what I get:

[image: import]

However, when using the require syntax, `const $ = require('jquery');`, Intellisense does work:

[image: require]

This happens with any kinds of import, not only with jquery.

Any way to make Intellisense work when using the import syntax? I am using typings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version 1 (released April 14th 2016), you need a `jsconfig.json` file at the root of your project with the following content in order to enable Intellisense with the `import` syntax:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is know bug. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/61

Fix is already available in [Insiders build](http://code.visualstudio.com/download?insiders=true). Or you can wait for the stable version 1.0, which will be released in few days.