# How to make the JavaScript Intellisense works at VSCode 1.0

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I'm trying the Visual Studio Code 1.0 but the new Intellisense called 'Salsa' is not working for me. I have the fallow project:

```
App
├── index.html
├── jsconfig.json
├── main.js 
├── lib
│   └── require.js
└── js
    └── pet.js
```

jsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

pet.js:

```
define(function () {
    var Pet = function(name) {
        this.name = name;

        this.getNameUpperCase = function(){
            return this.name.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    return Pet;
});
```

main.js (does not suggest me the method getNameUpperCase)

[image: main.js]

Please, what am I doing wrong?

[edit] the import of pet.js was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect.

`var Pet = require('./js/pet');`

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561203/why-do-i-get-intellisense-in-vscode-when-using-require-but-not-when-using-imp) if you would like to use the new `import` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post. The problem continues after my edit

Comment: You also pass `require` as an argument to your function, which shadows Node's `require` method. Remove the argument `require` and it should work.